# Override function error in swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I got a struct :

```
struct ErrorResultType: ErrorType {
    var description: String
    var code: Int
}
```

and a protocol:

```
protocol XProtocol {
    func dealError(error: ErrorResultType)
}
```

Now I want to make an extention of UIViewController:

```
extension UIViewController: XProtocol {

    func dealError(error: ErrorResultType) {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

So I can subclass from this and override the function like:

```
class ABCViewController: UIViewController {

--->override func dealError(error: ErrorResultType) {
        super.dealError(error)
        // do something custom
    }
}
```

But it goes wrong with: `Declarations from extensions cannot be overridden yet`

It doesn't make any sense to me. When I replace all `ErrorResultType` with `AnyObject`, the error won't appear any more.

Anything I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now the method in the extension must be marked with `@objc` to allow overriding it in subclasses.

```
extension UIViewController: XProtocol {

    @objc
    func dealError(error: ErrorResultType) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

But that requires all types in the method signature to be Objective-C compatible which your `ErrorResultType` is not. 
Making your `ErrorResultType` a class instead of a struct should work though.

Comment: Yes~It works! That's why using `AnyObject` is available. And the class of `ErrorResultType` must subclass from `NSObject` too, `ErrorType` is swift class/protocol. It's a pity that I can't use struct, struct is more appropriate than class here.

Answer (score 1):

If i am not making mistake this is connected with Swift official extension mechanism for adding methods to classes.

Conclusion :

> At the moment, it's not possible to override entities declared in
>   extension by subclassing, like so:

```
class Base { }

extension Base {
    var foo: String { return "foo" }
}

class Sub: Base {
    override var foo: String { return "FOO" } // This is an error
}
```

Please check this resource for more information : https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux/blob/master/README.md#overriding-declarations-from-extensions

Comment: Yes,It does some work if I change extension to a new Class. And I overridden the function in subclass, the error disappeared. But I'm still confused. Why using `AnyObject` won't cause this problem.

Comment: And the most important thing, I want to add a base function to UIViewController without subclass from UIViewController